# Delete rows in oracle from vb.net textbox

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

How to delete all rows in oracle table based on values in vb.net textbox?
This code delete only first row from textbox in oracle table :

```
For Each name As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
str = "Delete from table_1 where column1 in ('" & name & "')"
```

Where i go wrong with this code?

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
Public Class Form1

Private cmd As OracleCommand
Private da As OracleDataAdapter
Private cb As OracleCommandBuilder
Private ds As DataSet

Private Sub Connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click


    Dim conn As New OracleConnection
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim lstParameterValues As New List(Of String)
    Dim HardReturn As String() = {vbNewLine}
    Dim query As New StringBuilder("Delete from table_1")


    Try

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + "fghfhfh" &
      ";Password=" + "353525346" &
      ";Data Source=" + " dfgdg "
            conn.Open()
        End If


        Connect.Enabled = False



        For Each name As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(HardReturn, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            lstParameterValues.Add(name)
        Next

            Select Case lstParameterValues.Count
                Case 1
                    query.Append(" WHERE column1 = @column1")
                cmd.Parameters.name("@column1", lstParameterValues(0))
            Case Is > 1
                    query.Append(" WHERE column1 IN (")

                    Dim paramName As String

                    For index As Integer = 0 To lstParameterValues.Count - 1 Step 1
                        paramName = "@column1" & index

                        If index > 0 Then
                            query.Append(", ")
                        End If

                        query.Append(paramName)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, lstParameterValues(index))
                    Next index

                    query.Append(")")
            End Select



        cmd = New OracleCommand(str, conn)
            da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
            cb = New OracleCommandBuilder(da)
            ds = New DataSet()

            da.Fill(ds)


    Finally

        Connect.Enabled = True

    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

The code is improved like the comments from @mary, but i got this errors:

- BC30456  'name' is not a member of 'OracleParameterCollection'
- BC30002 Type 'StringBuilder' is not defined.
- BC30456 'AddWithValue' is not a member of 'OracleParameterCollection'.
- BC30455  Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'.

Comment: What does the `TextBox` actually contain?

Comment: I suggest that you [check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298).

Comment: TextBox contain values from  column1

Comment: i can't find on that link what i need

Comment: Yes you can.  You just don't know what you're looking for.  That example shows you how to build a single SQL statement with multiple values in an `IN` clause from a list in VB.  That's exactly what you want to do.  You probably ought to start by learning the basics of ADO.NET, which includes using parameters to insert values into SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

The comment and link by @jmcilhinney is what you need because Parameters are essential to protect your data.

```
 Dim lstParameterValues As New List(Of String)
 Dim HardReturn As String() = {vbNewLine}
 For Each name As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(HardReturn, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     lstParameterValues.Add(name)
 Next
```

Now that you have a list just substitute into @jmcilhinney's code thusly...

```
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    Dim query As New StringBuilder("Delete FROM MyTable")
    Select Case lstParameterValues.Count
        Case 1
            query.Append(" WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn")
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyColumn", lstParameterValues(0))
        Case Is > 1
            query.Append(" WHERE MyColumn IN (")

            Dim paramName As String

            For index As Integer = 0 To lstParameterValues.Count - 1 Step 1
                paramName = "@MyColumn" & index

                If index > 0 Then
                    query.Append(", ")
                End If

                query.Append(paramName)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, lstParameterValues(index))
            Next index

            query.Append(")")
    End Select

    command.CommandText = query.ToString()
    command.Connection = connection
```

Comment: BC30456 'name' is not a member of 'OracleParameterCollection'
The lin3
`cmd.Parameters.name("@column1", lstParameterValues(0))`
should be as in my answer
`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyColumn", lstParameterValues(0))`
.AddWithValue not .name

Comment: BC30002 Type 'StringBuilder' is not defined.
Add `Imports System.Text` to the top of the file.
Intellisense in Visual Studio should have shown you this fix when you hover your mouse over the red squiggly under StringBuilder.

Comment: BC30456 'AddWithValue' is not a member of 'OracleParameterCollection'.
 The example provided by @ jmcilhinney was intended for Microsoft SQL Server and needs to be adjusted for Oracle. When I Google OracleParameterCollection I find "Add(String, Object) 
Adds an OracleParameter to the OracleParameterCollection given the parameter name and value." at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparametercollection?view=netframework-4.7.2 This is the way to find answers. So, change any lines with ".AddWithValue" to just ".Add"

Comment: BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'. I do not see a line of code calling a function called Str. What line is causing this error?